# How to allow users to add images to an existing node?

Tags: 8

How to allow users to add images to an existing node without giving them access to the whole node edit page. In Drupal 7 i used the [Block Upload Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_upload) but it's buggy in the drupal 8 version. Do you have any approaches to get this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In D8 you can use a form mode for this to assign a reduced node edit page to a specific user role.

See https://www.drupal.org/project/form_mode_control